# I am unable to delete a compute instance group in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a compute instance group in GCP with terrafrom and when I am trying to delete it It is giving me an error that
`Failed to delete beta-instance-group: Operation type [compute.instanceGroupManagers.delete] failed with message "Required 'compute.instanceGroups.update' permission for 'projects/194091846614/zones/europe-central2-c/instanceGroups/beta-instance-group'"`

Investigation:-
I check in the equivalent REST of this instance group and found that the service account associated is `194091846614@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` . I tried to search for that in IAM but I am able to find it. Hence I am unable to grant it the required permission and delete it. I also tried to delete it with cloud CLI but its showin same error.

What should I do to delete it since I did this with terraform my tf state is also stuck.

Comment: Ignore `194091846614@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`. That is not your problem. The credentials that `you` are using do not have permission.

Comment: let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to delete the Compute instance group due to permission issue follow the below steps to resolve your issue:

1. Check whether the service account (`194091846614@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`) is not deleted. You can do that by going to `IAM and Admin> IAM >` check for your service account.
2. If you find the service account, look for an account named '`Google API Service Agent`' with the member as `'project number@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`'.Make sure that this account is present in the project with  '`roles/editor`' permission assigned to it.

Below predefined roles should be sufficient:

> [`roles/compute.admin`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute.instanceAdmin.v1) Full control of all Compute Engine
> resources.
>
> [`roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute.instanceAdmin.v1) when all resources are in one
> project.
>
> [`roles/compute.networkUser`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute.networkUser) on the project where the network is
> defined.
>
> [`roles/compute.imageUser`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute.imageUser) on the project where the image is
> defined.

3. If you don’t find the service account try creating one and assign the required permissions and delete the instance.

Comment: when i try to create a service account it is getting created as ```<id>@asm-development-372106.iam.gserviceaccount.com``` not the one as i mentioned above. Is it possible to create google managed service account ?

Comment: You cannot manually create a google managed service account, If you don't find the google manage service account click on the Include Google-provided role grants as mentioned in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-types#google-managed-service-account-visibility).

Comment: If you still didn't find the service account only workaround is you need to manually add the service account `<id>@asm-development-372106.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to the project and grant it Editor role

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the credential you are using in Terraform has the appropriate permissions to perform the deletion for instance and instance groups.